# Y onclick mouse coordinate getting a lot of decimal numbers (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, debugging, decimal, mouseevent, coordinates

With the code below I am getting weird results for the Y mouse coordinate,

```
function checkClick() {
    document.onclick = getMouseXY;
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    function getMouseXY(e) {
        mouseX = e.clientX - rect.left;
        mouseY = e.clientY - rect.top;
        document.getElementById("tester").innerHTML = "x: " + mouseX + " y: " + mouseY;
    }
}
```

Example, I may get x: 400 y: -68.80000305175781

X is always integer, Y is giving me decimals :P why?

Comment: `getBoundingClientRect()` returns doubles rather than integers.

Comment: why isn't x getting decimals aswell? :|

Comment: Possibly related to vertical scroll or other placement. Does it really matter though? For most cases, you only need accuracy to the nearest integer.

Comment: It's really weird though. I have one line now with "math.round(..)" and the other one is normal

Comment: Well as I said, the properties in `getBoundingClientRect()` all have the potential to be doubles, so you might as well `Math.round()` both coordinates.